# Taking sum of list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to take the sum of a list in Haskell but it gives the error, please see the below code.

```
binListToDec :: [Int] -> Int
binListToDec (x:xs) = if length binListToDec == 0 then 1
                      else x + binListToDec xs
```

It gives the following error

```
 * No instance for (Foldable ((->) [Int]))
        arising from a use of `length'
    * In the first argument of `(==)', namely `length binListToDec'
      In the expression: length binListToDec == 0
      In the expression:
        if length binListToDec == 0 then 1 else x + binListToDec xs
  |
2 | binListToDec (x:xs) = if length binListToDec == 0 then 1
```

Comment: What is `length binListToDec` supposed to do?

Comment: take the length of the string passed to the function. and if its 0 ( empty) then return 1 as the sum @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: but (a) the list you pass is `(x:xs)` and (b) the length can never be zero, since `(x:xs)` is the pattern for a non-empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among the myriad ways you could write this, two possibilities would be

```
binListToDec xs = if length xs == 0 then 0  -- see below
                  else (head xs) + binListToDec (tail xs)
```

and

```
binListToDec [] = 0
binListToDec (x:xs) = x + binListToDec xs
```

You appear to be trying to combine bits of each. There's no way to write a single pattern that matches simultaneously 1) an empty list and 2) a non-empty list with 3) its head and tail matched separately.

- `xs` matches 1) and 2).
- `all@(x:xs)` matches 2) and 3)
- <strike>1) and 3) cannot be matched</strike>, because the pairing is nonsensical: an empty list doesn't have a separate head and tail. `[]` and `(x:xs)` match lists from two non-overlapping sets of possible list values.

  Update: there is a *lazy* pattern match `all@(~(x:xs))`. The tilde prevents the match `(x:xs)` from being attempted until there is a need to
  evaluate `x` or `xs`. We think of

  ```
  binListToDec all@(~(x:xs)) = if length all == 0 then 0 else x + binListToDec
  ```

  as equivalent to

  ```
  binListToDec all = if length all == 0 
                     then 0
                     else let (x:xs) = all 
                          in x + binListToDec
  ```

  A lazy pattern match can still fail, but here we defer using `x` and `xs` until we know it won't.

---

`length binListToDec` attempts to compute the length of the function itself, not the length of its argument, in your attempt. The correct argument for `length` is used above. Also, the generally accepted sum of an empty list is  0, not 1.

Comment: `all@(~(x:xs))` meets all three criteria. ...but that's not to say I recommend it. Just that it's possible. e.g. `binListToDec all@(~(x:xs)) = if length all == 0 then 0 else x + binListToDec xs` would work, though it would be slow for all the same reasons your first solution is.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks; I figured there was some bit of syntax I was forgetting about.